# Granting administrator consent for Outlook Add-in

Tags: azure-active-directory, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to create an Outlook add-in that supports SSO, by following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/authenticate-a-user-with-an-sso-token#get-the-sso-token). The one step that I can't get to work is manually granting my app permissions, using this page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/grant-admin-consent-to-an-add-in#feedback).

I'm prompted to login to my Office account after following the link in step 1, but I'm never asked to give permissions. I end up getting redirected to the following URL:

https://localhost:3000/?error=access_denied&error_description=AADSTS50020%3a+We+are+unable+to+issue+tokens+from+this+api+version+for+a+Microsoft+account.+Please+contact+the+application+vendor+as+they+need+to+use+version+2.0+of+the+protocol+to+support+this.%0d%0aTrace+ID%3a+8843753f-10ce-4ba4-87cb-5b4d5d357e00%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+bea9ab59-01af-47b4-909a-d470533d8fd2%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2018-08-22+09%3a43%3a07Z&admin_consent=True&tenant=9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad&state=12345

My office account is only an Office 365 personal account (rather than a work or school account). Could this be why I'm getting this error? Is there any other way for me to develop this add-in with user authentication?

Answer (score 1):

From the error message in the URL it looks like the SSO code is using [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) to access an Azure Active Directory v2.0 endpoint. AAD v2.0 is only supported by [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-libraries) . To know more about either libraries read [here](https://www.kompozure.com/blog/azure-ad-v2-and-msal-from-developers-point-of-view/)

Comment: +1. Strictly speaking you can use custom code to access AAD v2.0 instead of MSAL, if you want. But I think @Sanjay essentially correct. It looks like your code is trying to get a token from AAD v1.0. That won't work for SSO (regardless of whether you are using a Microsoft Account or an Office 365 account). SSO requires that you use AAD v2.0. If you haven't already, please carefully read the documentation that starts at this node of the help: [SSO in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins)